# Error -1072824317 trying to use MSMQ with WCF

Tags: wcf, wcf-security

I have a Silverlight client which is talking to a WCF Service and performing some actions

Most of the time these actions will be quick, but often they wont be so I need a way of avoiding WCF timeouts by essentially passing the work onto its own "thread" server side and having a way for the client to know when the operation has completed

I have searched on here and found reference to the article below

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163482.aspx

I have downloaded the sample

It was targeting .NET 2 so I have updated it to 4.5 and the required IDesign folder didn’t exist in c:\program files so I have created it

Once I installed MSMQ and tried to run the client I get the error below

```
HResult=-1072824317
Message=An error occurred while opening the queue:Unrecognized error -1072824317   (0xc00e0003). The  message cannot be sent or received from the queue. Ensure that MSMQ is installed and running. Also ensure that the queue is available to open with the required access mode
```

Does anyone know what the problem is here?  I am very new to MSMQ

I notice that this code is very old (2006), so is there a better way of doing this nowadays?

Paul

Comment: I have also not been able to get the series from here working http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tomholl/archive/2008/07/12/msmq-wcf-and-iis-getting-them-to-play-nice-part-1.aspx I am not sure if there are alternatives now?